# Envio de email SMTP no WordPress via servidor com certificado autoassinado

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp

Tenho um WordPress Multisite (4.3) em um servidor onde o envio de emails é bloqueado. Para enviar emails, deve ser usado um servidor externo com autenticação.

Por padrão, a função nativa `wp_mail()` do WordPress usa internamente o PHPMailer que por sua vez chama o `mail()` do PHP. Esse procedimento aparentemente não usa SMTP (?) e não permite configurar autenticação ou outras opções.

No passado, eu já havia usado o plugin [wp-mail-smtp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) para forçar o uso de SMTP e preencher os dados de autenticação.

Entretanto, o servidor de emails usa um certificado autoassinado e aparentemente a partir do PHP 5.6 (que é a versão usada pelo WP) introduziu validação de certificados, causando a falha no envio, a menos que eu utilize as seguintes parâmetros:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28759959/798677))

Eu consigo enviar emails com sucesso a partir de um script de teste. Mas não sei como forçar o WordPress a aplicar esta configuração. Nenhum plugin que eu encontrei as suporta, e [a solução que encontrei](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75957/22510) sugere editar o `functions.php`, o que a meu ver seria uma solução que se aplicaria somente àquele tema naquele site em particular.

Como proceder para que algo funcione para todos os sub-sites do multisite?

Answer (score 1):

É uma ferramenta interessante em *single sites*, mas quase que essencial para Multisites:

[Must Use Plugins « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)

Todos os scripts que colocar dentro da pasta `wp-content/mu-plugins` vão ser executados automaticamente sem necessidade de ativação, bem antes dos outros plugins e de maneira geral em todos os sites da rede.

Pode-se [restringir sua execução](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3426/12615) para este ou aquele site.

Que eu saiba, aquela solução do Eugene que encontrou é a que resolve seu problema, com atenção especial à [resposta do maestro Kaiser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103856/12615). É só criar um arquivo PHP com aquele código e colocá-lo dentro de `/mu-plugins`. Se colocar um [cabeçalho de plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72183/12615), a listagem fica mais elegante em `/wp-admin/network/plugins.php`

Como aparentemente não os conhece, ficam de referencia as várias respostas que escrevi usando os Must Use Plugins no [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12615%20mu-plugins) e no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1287812%20mu-plugins).